# Can gRPC set the global memory limit of client side for all the response messages

Tags: java, grpc

My application is using gRPC in JAVA. The response message size is random. The message size has a range from 1B to 2MB. If I reduce the concurrent request count, the performance is not expected when all the responses are 1B. If I increase the concurrent request count, the memory may not enough when all responses are 2MB.
So is there a global response memory limit, that I can increase request concurrence safely?

I can not find a config to limit the global memory usage

Comment: Is [ManagedChannelBuilder.maxInboundMessageSize](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ManagedChannelBuilder.html#maxInboundMessageSize(int)) what you're after?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems to be a memory limit for a single message, but not a global memory limit.

Comment: Well it's for a single response. I don't know what you'd mean by "a global memory limit". Do you mean you only want to process 2MB of messages in total for the whole time you're running? (How would you expect gRPC to know when you're "done" with one response?) I very much doubt that what you're after is available or feasible.

Comment: I want to set memory limit for Netty and gRPC. -- If I set Direct Memory to 1GB when average message size is 1KB, ideally I can run 1048576 concurrent streams. But if the average message size exceeds 1KB at some point, OOM will occur. So my question is: Is there a mechanism for gRPC/NETTY to stop receiving more data when a "memory threshold" is reached? @JonSkeet

Comment: I know there is a window size in gRPC and Netty. So the question seems to become: How much memory will gRPC and Netty use, based on the number of concurrent streams, window size, and max/average gRPC message size.

Comment: But again, you'd need to know when a particular message is "done". I'm afraid I don't think I'm going to be able to help you - and I *suspect* that what you're asking for just isn't available.

Comment: Did you actually experience OOM? Do you use https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/stub/CallStreamObserver.html#setOnReadyHandler(java.lang.Runnable) on the server side?

Comment: Yes, when the stream count is too high, direct memory OOM occured at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.expandCumulation. And "setOnReadyHandler" is used at server side.